# How to resolve "Multiple entries matched, please click to resolve."?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, ad, clientpeoplepicker

I am working with SharePoint Foundation 2013.

I have created a custom HTML page and kept a Client Side People Picker.

Now when I set the current user in People Picker I get following

[image]

There is no other user in AD with User1 as firstname, lastname, displayname.

The User1 is unique in AD.

Any help and suggestions is appreciated!!!

Comment: check the user info list as well once you clear it from there you won't see this error.